# Orthogonality of vectors and the orthogonal complement

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $W$ be a subspace of $R^n$ and $v$ a vector in $R^n$. Suppose that $w$ and $w'$ are orthogonal vectors with $w$ in $W$ and that $v$ = $w$ + $w'$. Is it necessarily true that $w'$ is in $W_(complement)$? Either prove that it is true or find a counterexample.

I have the feeling that the statement is not true. However, I find it hard to come up with a counterexample. How would I systematically find such an example? Could anyone help me out in giving one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $W$ is the space generated by the vectors $e_1,e_2$ from the standard ordered basis. Can you find two orthogonal vectors in $W$?

Comment: Yes, I think [0,1] and [1,0] would do, if I'm not mistaking. How would this help me though?

Comment: Do either of them lie in $W^\perp$? If not, then you have the counterexample you were looking for.

Comment: I don't think they do (intuitively), since both are in W and can thus not be in $W^⊥$. How could I check this? So could I take for instance $v=[1,1]^T$ as my counterexample?

Comment: The only vector that lies in both $W$ and $W^\perp$ is the zero vector, because non-zero vectors are not self-orthogonal. Hence, assuming that $n\ge2$, then taking $v=e_1+e_2,w=e_1,w'=e_2,W=\text{span}(e_1,e_2),$ we have that $w\in W$, $w'$ orthogonal to $w$, but $w'\notin W^{\perp}$.

Comment: Thank you for your help :D!